# Spring shutdown event that fires immediately before ApplicationContext is destroyed?

Tags: java, spring, destroy, applicationcontext

I am looking for an interceptor or a trigger to know that, all the context beans are destroyed and the applicationcontext instance is about to destroy itself. So I can do one process at the end of the application lifetime.

There is this event type ContextClosedEvent, which is close to the thing that I wanna do but, it throws the event *after* destruction of beans. I thing it comes with the close() method of the applicationcontext. So it doesn't fit to my need

Any ideas?

Regards

Ali

Comment: Out of curiosity, `ClosedContextEvent` [means](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) that at this moment there are no alive beans in the context, so, what are you interested in achieving? Isn't this actually what you need?

Comment: it is firing itself at the beginning of the disposal process. Like, for ex, at the beginning of context.close(). I want it at the end of it

Comment: Please read once more the link I provided. It exactly means the way you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use registerShutDownHook() method of the abstract application context class. For more details have a look at [this.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook%28%29)

**UPDATE**

Then you should try @PreDestroy annotation on top of the method where you want to run something in the end when the spring context is about to destroy.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Is there any decent sample for this usage? because, the samples that I have seen are not providing to link a method. Is there any basic usage sample like this?

Comment: Please check the below link for example. http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/registershutdownhook.html

Comment: I am looking for an entry point to run something in the end when the spring context is about be the destroyed. This sample is not something like that

Comment: They are all bean based solutions dude, I need to override context disposal mechanism of spring I think. I solved it depend-on attribute but , it is not a good solutions of course. I am still lookin for a new one

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean implementing SmartLifecycle, with a getPhase returning Integer.MAX_VALUE.
Its stop() method will be executed before any other stop or destroy methods.
You can there do cleanup on every resources in living beans.

```
    @Component
    public class Terminator implements SmartLifecycle {

        private boolean started = true;

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            // CLEANUP CODE
        }
        @Override
        public void stop(Runnable callback) {
            stop();
            callback.run();
        }

        @Override
        public int getPhase() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isAutoStartup() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return started;
        }

    }
```